# How do I do a drag and drop using jQuery to move data between two or more divs and then trigger an update to the db on the drop?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

How do I do a drag and drop using jQuery UI to move data between two or more divs?

I'm using jQuery and this is in conjunction with an asp.net core api.

This would essentially be like a calendar, being able to move entries between days.

The tutorials I've looked at don't cover exactly what I need to do. New Divs (or elements) will be created dynamically, and I've been unable to get the drap/drop to work in the dynamically created divs, even after applying droppable()/draggable() to the new elements.

I've included the html page below and css in a mock-up. The mock-up doesn't include any dynmaically-added elements to keep it simpler for now.

There are a series of divs in the mock-up that represent days. Each day contains event items that can be moved around to different days. If you imagine this when connected to a data source, where it says Monday, Tuesday etc will display the date.

But first of all, I need help with understanding how I get what I currently have to work without absolute positioning.

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1></h1>
    
    <div class='day' id='day1'>
        <h4>Monday</h4>
        <div id='3'>Breakfast</div>
        <div id='4'>Lunch</div>
        <div id='10'>Dinner</div>
    </div>
    <div class='day' id='day2'>
        <h4>Tuesday</h4>
        <div id='1'>Meeting with Jack</div>
        <div id='7'>Working lunch</div>
        <div id='8'>Phone call with Sarah</div>
        <div id='9'>Team meeting</div>
        <div id='12'>HR Review</div>
    </div>
    <div class='day' id='day3'>
        <h4>Wednesday</h4>
        <div id='5'>Progress update</div>
        <div id='6'>Call Simon</div>
    </div>
    <div class='day' id='day4'>
        <h4>Thursday</h4>
        <div id='2'>Drinks with Bob</div>
        <div id='11'>Weekly report</div>
    </div>
    <div class='day' id='day5'>
        <h4>Friday</h4>
        <div id='13'>Zoom meeting</div>
        <div id='14'>Email Jo</div>
        <div id='15'>Company Meal</div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.day div').draggable({
                helper: 'clone',
                cursor: 'move'
            });

            $('.day').droppable({
                tolerance: 'pointer',
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var id = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');
                    var eventItem = $(ui.draggable).html();
                    var day = $(this).attr('id');

                    // Here's where am ajax call will go 

                    $(ui.draggable).remove();
                    $('#' + day).append('<div id="' + id + '">' + eventItem + '</div>');
                    $('div#' + id).draggable({
                        helper: 'clone',
                        cursor: 'move'
                    });
                    $(this).css('min-height', 'auto');

                }
            });

        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;
    color: white;
    height: 20px;
}

h2 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 20px 20px;
    height: 25px;
}

h4 {
    margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    border-bottom-color: dimgrey;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}

div#left {
    margin-left: 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
}

div#center, div#right {
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

ul, ol {
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
}



li {
    padding: 0 10px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

    li:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #CCC;
    }

    li:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: white;
    }

    li:hover {
        cursor: move;
    }


.box {
    min-height: 100px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
}

.day {
    min-height: 100px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
}

    .day div {
        background-color:  #00122f;
        padding-top: 2px;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        padding-right: 1px;
        color: white;
        padding-left: 3px;
        
    }

#day1 {
    border-color: orange;
    left: 10px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 150px;
}

#day2 {
    border-color: blue;
    left: 200px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 150px;
}

#day3 {
    border-color: green;
    left: 390px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 150px;
}

#day4 {
    border-color: red;
    left: 580px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 150px;
}

#day5 {
    border-color: darkturquoise;
    left: 770px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 150px;
}

.instructions {
    color: red;
}


#reorder ul {
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

#reorder li {
    padding: 2px 20px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

#update-button, #update-message {
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

ol.indexpage {
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    list-style: decimal;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.indexpage li {
    border: none;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I don't have any code - I've not been able to find a tutorial that shows how to do this. I am trying to find out how to do it.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML Output of you Tables? You should have something to start with. You may also want to review: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Comment: I've updated the post with more details and code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using Sortable.

> The jQuery UI Sortable plugin makes selected elements sortable by dragging with the mouse.

Here is a basic example.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".day").sortable({
    connectWith: ".day",
    cursor: "move",
    helper: "clone",
    items: "> div",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      var $item = ui.item;
      var eventLabel = $item.text();
      var newDay = $item.parent().attr("id");
      
      console.log($item[0].id, eventLabel, newDay);

      // Here's where am ajax call will go
      
    }
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0 20px 20px;
  height: 25px;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  border-bottom-color: dimgrey;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}

div#left {
  margin-left: 40px;
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
}

div#center,
div#right {
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: move;
}

.box {
  min-height: 100px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
}

.day {
  min-height: 100px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
}

.day div {
  background-color: #00122f;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-right: 1px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

#day1 {
  border-color: orange;
  left: 10px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 150px;
}

#day2 {
  border-color: blue;
  left: 200px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 150px;
}

#day3 {
  border-color: green;
  left: 390px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 150px;
}

#day4 {
  border-color: red;
  left: 580px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 150px;
}

#day5 {
  border-color: darkturquoise;
  left: 770px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 150px;
}

.instructions {
  color: red;
}

#reorder ul {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#reorder li {
  padding: 2px 20px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

#update-button,
#update-message {
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ol.indexpage {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  list-style: decimal;
  border: none;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.indexpage li {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<h1></h1>

<div class='day' id='day1'>
  <h4>Monday</h4>
  <div id='3'>Breakfast</div>
  <div id='4'>Lunch</div>
  <div id='10'>Dinner</div>
</div>
<div class='day' id='day2'>
  <h4>Tuesday</h4>
  <div id='1'>Meeting with Jack</div>
  <div id='7'>Working lunch</div>
  <div id='8'>Phone call with Sarah</div>
  <div id='9'>Team meeting</div>
  <div id='12'>HR Review</div>
</div>
<div class='day' id='day3'>
  <h4>Wednesday</h4>
  <div id='5'>Progress update</div>
  <div id='6'>Call Simon</div>
</div>
<div class='day' id='day4'>
  <h4>Thursday</h4>
  <div id='2'>Drinks with Bob</div>
  <div id='11'>Weekly report</div>
</div>
<div class='day' id='day5'>
  <h4>Friday</h4>
  <div id='13'>Zoom meeting</div>
  <div id='14'>Email Jo</div>
  <div id='15'>Company Meal</div>
</div>
```

Sortable combines Drag and Drop elements and allows the lists to be connected. So items from Monday can be dragged to any day of the week and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks. Can this same approach be done with <li> elements across different divs with their own <ul>s ?

Comment: Yes it can. That is the default Item.